# Does Firefox OS synchronize platform and kernel for display?

Tags: firefox-os, vsync

Can someone help me understand how display rate is synchronized between platform and kernel. Because I am unable to see the use of vsync, as we used to do in Android ?

So I wanted to know how firefox os do it ?

Comment: According to f.e. [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980241) it uses vsync.

Answer (score 0):

window.requestAnimationFrame() (or use a JavaScript framework that uses it)